# How to Set Item source for WPF toolkit auto complete box inside dataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, toolkit, autocompletebox

I have the following ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbListItems"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="956">
                        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acbItem"</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can I set the ItemsSource for acbItem in code behind ?
I cant access to it !

Comment: I bind the ItemsSource property for the Listbox but it does not work, If I put the Listbox out of template it works !

Comment: Then you should specify a RelativeSource of the binding. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Loaded` event is a solution.

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Loaded="myControl_Loaded" ...

private void myControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    toolkit:AutoCompleteBox myCombo = sender as toolkit:AutoCompleteBox; 
    // Do things..
}
```

But it's better to use MVVM approach to set `ItemsSource` from `XAML`

Comment: I bind the ItemsSource property for the Listbox in XAML but it does not work, If I put the Listbox out of template it works !
Any way .. your solution works, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I bind the ItemsSource property for the Listbox but it does not work, If I put the Listbox out of template it works !

Then you should specify a `RelativeSource` of the binding:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acbItem" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.YourItemsSourceCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
```

Simply replace "YourItemsSourceCollection" with the actual name of the propertty to bind to and keep the rest.